# How can I update text-label in d3 donut according with my array's data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i am trying to add the percentage instead of labels [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jvalleo17/4L8fphsu/10/)  according with array.
I need label to be updated after every donut's transition. If I insert just `.text(function (d) { return d.data.value;});`
it shows me only the second array's value and doesn't change. How can I fix it?

PS: I saw some similar questions here - but I cant intergate their solution to my donut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the label on the end of the transition:

```
slice       
    .transition().duration(1000)
        .each("end", function(d,i){
            d3.selectAll('.labels text')
                .text(function(d) {
                  return (((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2 * Math.PI)) * 100).toFixed(0) + '%';
                })
            })
    .attrTween("d", function(d) {
        this._current = this._current || d;
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
        this._current = interpolate(0);
        return function(t) {
            return arc(interpolate(t));
        };
    });
```

Updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4L8fphsu/14/).

Comment: Thanks for solution, works great. 
could you tell - if is it possible insert the different text inside the donut for every transition?

Comment: @SpiritBreak, I don't understand.  You want the labels on the donut instead of outside of it?

Comment: nope, I want insert new title-label in the center of the donut - so when the first transition ends (percent and slice sizes) - the title-label changes to the next from array for the second transition (new perc. and new slice sizes) and etc.
created new array and classes - but it doesnt work( [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvalleo17/4L8fphsu/17/)

Comment: I did it!  here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvalleo17/4L8fphsu/19/)
just added the .each function and additional field in array and it works!
 how can I count the center of the word inside? because if the word shorter or bigger it isn't centered, looks not pretty.

Comment: got it -`.attr("text-anchor","middle")`